# is vb.net row-major or column-major in 2d array allocation?

Tags: vb.net

is vb.net row-major or column-major in 2d array allocation?

Comment: i posted the solution with code on my blog www.alitarhini.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET stores 2D arrays in Row Major order.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). (about half-way down!)

[CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (section 8.9.1) states:

> Array elements shall be laid out
>   within the array object in row-major
>   order (i.e., the elements associated
>   with the rightmost array dimension
>   shall be laid out contiguously from
>   lowest to highest index). The actual
>   storage allocated for each array
>   element can include platform-specific
>   padding.

Comment: yeah this is my tendency to think but is there a reference to be certain?

Comment: great! thanks, i am assuming that c# stores arrays in the same way. what do you think ?

Comment: Yes. Is more to do with the way the CLI stores them rather than C# or VB.NET.